# How to hide warning 30 using [@ocaml.warning "-30"]

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have two records depending on each other and they both have a field with the same name. How to use the `ocaml.warning` attribute to hide this warning? I'd like to avoid something like `[@@@ocaml.warning "-30"] my types here [@@@ocaml.warning "+30"]`.

```
# type a = {a : int;} and b = { a:int;};;
Characters 30-36:
Warning 30: the label a is defined in both types a and b.
type a = { a : int; }
and b = { a : int; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be any better than the bracketing construct you want to avoid, but it works for me:

```
# module M = struct
    type a = {a: int} and b = {a: int}
  end [@warning "-30"];;
module M : sig type a = { a : int; } and b = { a : int; } end
# type a = M.a and b = M.b;;
type a = M.a
and b = M.b
```

Comment: I think that you may want to use `include M` instead of `type a = M.a ... `. Otherwise, you still need to prefix field accesses with `M`